# Yahoo Pipes Keep Old RSS Feeds From Publishing

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I have a Yahoo Pipe, were I am trying to prevent old RSS feeds from getting published. I've tried it with a Filter and if a have a look at the preview it seems to be working just as expected. But if I subscribe to the feed, I still receive old newsfeeds.

Here's a screenshot of the filter

[image]

Does anybody know why that happens?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to work now. After fumbling around with the pipes for some time, i ended up just creating it from scratch. This time it works for some strange reason.

It seems to me that Yahoo Pipes sometimes just don't update a Pipe, even when I save it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the reason, but I think maybe it has to be date builder, plugging into date formatter which then feeds into the filter. It doesnt look like the date is wired in correctly... as it usually shows something like "text [wired]" when I wire like that. Try using the Date formatter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I've tried that and now indeed, it says `text [wired]`. But still after subscribing to the new pipe, it shows me all the feeds from the source RSS Feed. It really is strange, since in the preview panel of Yahoo Pipes, it -again- shows the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

How did you format the date? Did you format it the same as the feed you are using has the date formatted?

More info on formatting the date: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=date#DateFormatter